# How to write json api model for request model

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-api-gateway, serverless

In my `serverless.yml` script I define the General Request model with:

```
    models:
      - name: "GeneralRequest"
        description: "General Request model"
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema: ${{file(my_api_models/generalRequest.json)}}
```

I go ahead and create json file saving it in the `my_api_models` folder as `generalRequest.json`. Here is the context of this file:

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "General Request",
  "type" : "object"
}
```

It works well. Next I want to add two parameters that the request should contain: the `first_name` and the `last_name`. I want the `first_name` to be required, while the `last_name` parameter will be optional. I go ahead and edit the `generalRequest.json` by adding these two parameters:

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "General Request",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "first_name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "last_name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  },
  
  "required": ["first_name"]
}
```

While it seems to be working well, I am not able to specify what kind of parameters the `first_name` and `last_name` are. As we know there is a number of different kind of parameters,
such as Path Parameters, Query Parameters and Request Body parameters.

Is there a way to specify what parameters types are in the json model script?

Answer (score 0):

Models work on the *payload* of the request, i.e. those are all request body parameters.

The `models` section allows you to specify models to API Gateway and use it with the serverless functions.

> Models are JSON Schemas that define the structure of request or response bodies. This includes property structure, their types and their validation.

Source: [Plugin documentation](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-aws-documentation)

See also "[Working with models and mapping templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html)" for the underlying AWS API Gateway feature and "[Understanding JSON Schema](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/)".

To define path & query parameters use the `request`/`parameters` section of the function definition, see "[Request Parameters](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-parameters)".